# Documentation on Gazebo Trivial Physics Engine

Tags: gazebo, physics, physics-engine

A few years ago, Trivial Physics Engine (TPE) [was announced](https://community.gazebosim.org/t/announcing-new-physics-engine-tpe-trivial-physics-engine/629) for Gazebo Sim.

I don't seem to find any documentation though.

- Would anyone know of a project that uses this? Drone swarm simulation maybe?
- Can someone explain what it does?

  - I assume it has no dynamics, and motion is realized by applying velocity commands?
  - But it does support collision. How can collision impacts be handled if there are no dynamics? Or does it just *detect* collisions (as a sort of error condition), and other than that, the objects continue moving according to their set velocity (i.e. through each other, unless the velocity commands are changed accordingly)?
- How can this be used: is it by adding a `VelocityControl` system plugin to each model that needs to move, and writing code to publish the corresponding velocity setpoints for each object?

Answer (score 2):

The documentation on *using* TPE is really scarce and scattered.

There is a lot of [developer documentation](https://gazebosim.org/api/physics/7/usecustomengine.html) explaining how custom physics plugins work, usually using TPE as a demonstration.

The only examples on how to use it are actually given in the announcement post:

```
ign gazebo --force-version 4 velocity_control.sdf --physics-engine ignition-physics-tpe-plugin
```

This is for Dome. I haven't found Fortress/Garden/Harmonic instructions and I don't have a working install of these at hand right now, but I guess the right command line could be something like this for Fortress:

```
gz sim velocity_control.sdf --physics-engine gz-physics6-tpe-plugin
```

(unfortunately, it seems the physics version number slipped into the engine plugin name...)

The `velocity_control.sdf` world also shows a way to control objects: [via `VelocityControl` system](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/blob/a88340b0d535905765aeaa41aab7b4d177fa6522/examples/worlds/velocity_control.sdf#L443-L448).

> But it does support collision.

I think this is a misunderstanding of the announcement. It says TPE supports *collision detection*. It means exactly that. It detects contacts between collision elements, but these contacts do not affect the behavior of the models. But you can e.g. subscribe to the contacts in your custom code and react to them.

The general idea of TPE was speeding up swarm simulations. There is even the [performance report](https://docs.google.com/document/d/16PfhDd2eSl-QdJFPY52-nV8zDLnYfyFAbX8wHCkRjO4/edit#heading=h.b8x7k6bpzd7) showing TPE to be ~2x faster than DART in a world with 9000 objects. Still, the RTF is 0.5%, but that's way better than 0.25% with DART. I don't know any particular project using TPE, but I can easily imagine that if you simulate control of drone swarms, you use TPE and just check if the drones do not collide using your control algorithm.

Comment: Martin's summary of TPE is on point. It's designed for simulating swarm of robots and offers velocity control for them via the `VelocityControl` system. It was originally implemented for the OpenRMF project that involves a large number of  heterogeneous robots roaming in multiple floors inside a building. One note is that majority of TPE's computation is in collision checking (14 out of 16ms in the report). So in theory you can get better RTF if you don't care about collisions: https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-physics/blob/af58fa57acfe74a12bd99062e0c096ea7678d18f/tpe/lib/src/World.cc#L86-L87

Comment: Another note is that TPE was originally created for mobile robots. It does not support joints. TPE is currently being maintained only but not actively developed.

Comment: The only project I know that is using it is [open-rmf](https://github.com/open-rmf/rmf_demos) where you can pass `use_tpe:=true` when launching demos.